# SIP Offer Answer Model

Tags: asterisk, sip

I am having a confusion regarding SIP Offer-Answer model. The scenario is like this.

I configured two accounts on my client side (Say A and B) with asterisk server and making a call from A to B.

Account Details of A

Client Side(Application) : A having video codec H264, Audio codecs G722,G711

Server Side(Asterisk)    : No video Codec, Audio codecs G722,G711

Account Details of B

Client Side(Application) : No video Codec,Audio codecs G722,G711

Server Side(Asterisk)    : No video Codec,Audio codecs G722,G711

In the first INVITE(offer) i am sending the SDP with "m=" parameter for both audio and video (video port as 52162) and asterisk is sending me the answer with "m=" parameter for both audio and video (video port as 0) on 183 session progress and 200 OK, (because asterisk is not having any video codec).

From application side i am sending next INVITE to put the call on hold. For that i am sending a=sendonly and "m=" parameter only for audio.

My doubt is "Can I avoid from application side "m=" parameter for video for the second INVITE(in my case it is hold)", if i am getting answer with video port as 0 for the first offer.

Answer (score 2):

The SIP offer/answer model requires that you re-use **all m=** lines in **same order** in all modifications of the session.

The only allowed action is to add additional m= lines **below** the existing ones.

In your use-case, if you don't include the **m=video** line, the remote side is supposed to reject your INVITE.

EDIT: Here is the exact wording from the rfc which clearly shows the requirements to never remove any m= lines:

From rfc3264 Section **8 Modifying the Session**

```
If an SDP is offered, which is different from the previous SDP, the
new SDP MUST have a matching media stream for each media stream in
the previous SDP.  In other words, if the previous SDP had N "m="
lines, the new SDP MUST have at least N "m=" lines.  The i-th media
stream in the previous SDP, counting from the top, matches the i-th
media stream in the new SDP, counting from the top.  This matching is
necessary in order for the answerer to determine which stream in the
new SDP corresponds to a stream in the previous SDP.  Because of
these requirements, the number of "m=" lines in a stream never
decreases, but either stays the same or increases.  Deleted media
streams from a previous SDP MUST NOT be removed in a new SDP;
however, attributes for these streams need not be present.
```

As a sidenote, it's useful to indicate an exception where the m= line *type* (audio, video, ...) MAY be modified: It's provided in Section **8.3.3 Changing Media Types**. This exception is very specific and won't apply in 99,99%... (example from rfc is voiceband fax to fax)

Comment: That not always true. Actually that is RECOMMENDED, but application can do on it own(like xlite's video in midle of call do)

Comment: @arheops: I have edited my answer and have added clear statements from the rfc3264. I do think my answer is correct! I have also never seen a different behavior in xlite? let me know if I missed something...

Comment: AymericM answer is correct. That's what a well behaved UA should do. However I agree with @arheops that there are many UAs and network elements that will not mind if you don't follow those rules strictly, applying the [Robustness principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle).

Comment: @jsantander: You are right! Accepting broken SDP is not that bad! *Be conservative in what you send, be liberal in what you accept*: that means you **MAY** accept broken incoming SDP. But still you **MUST NOT** send broken SDP (which was the question!).